# How to capture territories with no numbers printed on them?

Tags: axis-and-allies

In a&a 1941 if japan conducts an amphibious assault on soviet far east can she capture it? If yes, then does she still put the controller marker and does nothing else? (I mean no adding anything to japans national production chart since the territory of soviet far east does not have any number printed on it)

Answer (score 1):

Correct. A Japanese marker is placed on it as it is a captured territory by the enemy and should be treated as such by the allies.

I.e. allies can't land on it without taking it, it can't be blitzed through it without battling units in it etc.

Simply up it just had no IPC value.